# how to trim a list of urls to first folder

Tags: regex, string, url, url-rewriting, notepad++

I would like to trim a list of urls to first folder

```
for example:
url.com/folder1/xxx/index.html
url.com/folder2/
url.com/folder3/xxx/yyyy/index.html
url.com/folder4/zzz/aaa/bbb/index.html

Output should look like this:
url.com/folder1/
url.com/folder2/
url.com/folder3/
url.com/folder4/
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You don't provide any details about _how_ this should be done, where the Output should go etc,. Your question is tagged [regex[ and [notepad++] but other than that we have no context for your problem.

Comment: i tried doing it in scrapebox but it only trims to last folder not first.I have no experience with notepad++ or regex ,searched on google with no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find what:**

```
^([^/]*/[^/]*/).*
```

**OR**

Escape the forward slashes if necessary.

```
^([^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/).*
```

**Replace with:**

```
\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aS7zX3/1)

Comment: add `hhtp://` at the start in the replacement string. see https://regex101.com/r/aS7zX3/3

Comment: Sorry i'm new here ...i just signed up so bare with me :) ...what i ment to say is that if the originial urls haves http:// in it ...so (http://url.com/folder1/zzz/index.html) -> (http://url.com/folder1/)   .I couldn't add http:// in my original post because i'm a new user i cannot post more then 1 or 2 urls.

Answer (score 1):

**Find:**    `^.*?\/.*?\/\K.*$`

Try this.**Replace by** `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/14

`\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match`